# Show archive blog posts by year

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show blog posts by year, however I cannot bring up the blog posts, do I need to reloop?

I want a archive section that returns the blog post under the year in a dropdown fashion - you can see an example [here](https://www.targetis.co.uk/news-articles/)

```
<?php

$monthText = "";
$link_archive="";
$i=1;

$query1="SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`date`) AS `Year` FROM posts WHERE type='news' GROUP BY `Year` ORDER BY `date` DESC";
$sql1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
$sql1->execute();

while ($row1 = $sql1->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ )) {
    $inner_posts="";

    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $row1->Month);
    $year = $row1->Year;

    $query2="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type='news' AND YEAR(`date`) = ? ORDER BY `date` DESC";
    $sql2 = $dbh->prepare($query2);
    $sql2->execute([$year]);
while ($row2 = $sql2->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ )) {
    $inner_posts.="<div class='post'>
                <h2><a href='/{$GLOBALS['post_url']}/{$row->url}'>$row->title</a></h2>
                $blog_post_sh
              </div>";
}

if ($inner_posts != '') {
    $inner_posts = "<ul id='list{$i}' class='inner_posts'>{$inner_posts}</ul>";
}



$monthText.="<li>
<a class='open{$i}' href='/{$GLOBALS['posts_url']}$link_archive'>
{$year}
</a>
{$inner_posts}
</li>";
$i++;

}


?>

<ul>
    <?php echo $monthText; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are re-assigning `$inner_posts` after the loop, thereby overwriting all the post links assigned within the loop

Comment: How do you mean

Comment: `$inner_posts = "<ul id='list{$i}' class='inner_posts'>{$inner_posts}</ul>";` is declared after your while loop where you are populating it with links to your blog posts. In the loop you are using `$inner_posts.=`, which is concatenating each post onto the string, but then you overwrite all of it right after the loop

Comment: `$inner_posts = "...";` replaces everything that was assigned to `$inner_posts` in your while loop

Comment: I'm not what you mean, the $inner_posts = "" has a !. Are you able to show me by editing the code?

Comment: I misinterpreted your code. All those divs with the links appear to be going inside an unordered list, but not as list items. Are you using Smarty or some other template engine? The curly braces are not typical within normal PHP code

Comment: Using my own template engine. The issue is they show the right amount of posts, but it just shows the first blog entry from the database each time. So blog post 1 is shown 8 times rather than all 8 individual posts.

Comment: The loop iterates through `$row2` but the linking inside the loop references `$row` instead. I don't see an assignment for `$row` in this code